# Combobox Shows Type Name Instead of Display Name in Property Grid (Xceed WPF Toolkit)

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, propertygrid, xceed

I use Property Grid control of [a Extended WPF Toolkit](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PropertyGrid&referringTitle=Home) and need to show a list of accounts, loaded dynamically through a REST call. The Enum type shows well in the ComboBox editor while dynamic list does show type names instead of DisplayName of Item class. I used ItemsSourceAttribute and tried making Editor explicit through `[Editor(typeof(ItemsSourceAttributeEditor), typeof(ItemsSourceAttributeEditor))]` but both don't work.

Here is the appropriate code section.

*MainWindow.xaml*

```
<Window x:Class="PropertyGridXceedDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="600">
    <Grid>
        <xctk:PropertyGrid Margin="0,62,0,35" Name="control" AutoGenerateProperties="True" ShowSortOptions="False"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

*MainWindow.xaml.cs*

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.control.SelectedObject = new Settings();
    }
}
```

*Settings.cs*

```
[Serializable]
[DisplayName("Settings")]
public class Settings
{
    public Settings()
    {
        _mAccounts = new List<string>();
    }

    private DefaultOrderTypes _mOrderType= (DefaultOrderTypes)1;        
    private string _account = "Account-1";
    private List<string> _mAccounts;

    public enum DefaultOrderTypes
    {
        OrderType1,
        OrderType2
    };

    [Category("General"), Description("Select order type")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [DisplayName("Enum List")]
    public DefaultOrderTypes DefaultOrderType
    {
        get
        {
            return _mOrderType;
        }
        set
        {
            _mOrderType = value;
        }
    }

    [Category("General"), Description("Select account to use")]
    [DisplayName("Select Account")]
    [Editor(typeof(ItemsSourceAttributeEditor), typeof(ItemsSourceAttributeEditor))]
    [ItemsSource(typeof(AccountsItemSource))]        
    public string Account
    {
        get
        {
            return _account;
        }
        set
        {
            _account = value;
        }
    }
}
```

*AccountsItemSource.cs*

```
[Serializable]
public class AccountsItemSource : IItemsSource
{
    public Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.Attributes.ItemCollection GetValues()
    {
        Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.Attributes.ItemCollection c = new Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.Attributes.ItemCollection();
        c.Add(new Item { DisplayName = "Account-1",Value="Account-1" });
        c.Add(new Item { DisplayName = "Account-2", Value = "Account-2" });
        return c;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Account
{
    public Account(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if ( !(obj is Account) ) return false;
        return string.Compare(this.Name, ((Account)obj).Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }
}
```

The output shows like this:

```
Settings
    General
        Enum List          Proper combobox
        Select Account     Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.Attributes.Item
                           Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.Attributes.Item
```

Please advice. I can send sample application in email if required.

Best,
Shany